# Is this any way to find selected index id (selected record key value) of selected item of datalist without using SelectedIndexChanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

Is this any way to find selected record key value of selected item of datalist?

What is am doing is

```
  protected void dlstSelectedImages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int indexId = Convert.ToInt32(dlstSelectedImages.DataKeys[dlstSelectedImages.SelectedIndex]);

    }
```

But my datalist SelectedIndexChanged is not firing (Itried with: View State="Enable", AutoEventWireup="true", AutopostBack="true" for firing the event ), so Is there anyother way to get the SelectedIndexChanged id or selected record key value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call `dlstSelectedImages.SelectedIndex` at any time to get the currently selected index. It doesn't have to reside in an SelectedIndexChanged event handler. SelectedIndex is zero based and its default value is -1.

The SelectedIndexChanged event fires whenever the selected index changes (i.e. whenever SelectedIndex is assigned a new value). Typically, this would be on an ItemCommand or some other event:

```
  void Item_Command(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e) 
  {
     // Set the SelectedIndex property to select an item in the DataList.
     dlstSelectedImages.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;

     // Rebind the data source to the DataList to refresh the control.
     dlstSelectedImages.Rebind();
  }
```